# How can I keep bugs out of a basement?

Tags: basement, sealing, insect

I can't believe this hasn't been asked before.  But with covid-19, I've started working i my previously unused basement.  It's half finished, half not.  And in the finished rooms I've been noticing on a weekly basis some centipede will just come trotting across the floor or wall like it owns the place.

I've been aware of the centipedes ever since the house was built 7 years ago because I put sticky traps out for spiders and caught way more than I ever wanted to know about.  But they basically never came upstairs and the basement was vacant for years.  So I didn't care for all that time.

But now, they need to disappear.  I'm not really interested in the koom-bay-yah: love nature, they kill the bad insects nonsense.

So.  How should I go about keeping them out?  Or how can I find out where they're coming in and seal it?

The humidity doesn't feel abnormal.  There's no obvious food source.

The unfinished basement does have a sump pump, and one break in the concrete floor to access plumbing.  There's a couple floor drains.

The finished part is solid drywall with the only openings being outlets, a closed daylight window, and the occasional HVAC register.  (Though the HVAC is never in exterior walls.)

I suppose there is no airtight seal between the carpet and the baseboard either.

I know that there is about a half inch gap between the studs and the concrete wall.  I observed it during construction and they explained it was so that air could circulate to help dry the concrete if there were ever a leak.

I pulled the front plate off an outlet, scraped out a little notch in the drywall, and stuck a bore scope back there to look around.  I saw fiberglass, which I was not expecting...  I saw no wetness, but I left it on for several hours, and did see a couple bugs pass by on a couple occasions.  It's hard to say if they were attracted to the light on the scope, or if they were there anyway.  The carpet beneath this outlet plate happened to have some dead rollie polies on the carpet below so....

I'd rather not deal with insecticides because I don't want a recurring procedure and cost.  I'd prefer to find where they're coming from and seal that up.

Surely they don't come through the concrete walls right?  So where do they usually get in to houses?

UPDATE 2020-05-07:  On my hunch that they were coming through an outlet, I took a USB endoscope and stuck it in-between a junction box and the drywall with the cover plate off.  I left it up on screen while I worked for the last couple weeks, and tonight I saw motion and hit screenshot.  Look what I caught!
[image: house centipede in-between drywall and concrete]
[image: house centipede in wall at distance]
This outlet is maybe 3 foot to the side of a 'basement egress window' in a 2-foot-deep well.  So I wonder if they're not getting in through that.

What kind of poisons could I spray into the wall area to kill these suckers without damaging my home?  I'm ready to take the covers off ALL the outlets and just dump shit back in there if it would help.

Would wasp-spray / RAID work alright for this?  I imagine I could fashion an extension or cut the nosel so it fits im the small space i have to work with.

Comment: Insects enter via the smallest of openings and there is little you can do but find and seal them up.

Comment: Nothing complicated - poisons and detailed crack sealing. If you don't want to repeatedly poison, you have to be **really good** at crack sealing... Which is why most people who don't get along with bugs poison repeatedly.

Comment: You certainly aren't interested in the kum-ba-yah.  Sticky glue traps are wretchedly cruel.

Comment: How should I crack seal at the bottom of a wall in a carpeted room?  between the baseboard and carpet?  I'm thinking the styrofoam rubber rods that you use for expansion joints in concrete work and jam em in there with a plastic putty knife so the whole 'seam' between the carpet and baseboard is under pressure.  Other ideas?